# Why does using tanh worsen accuracy so much?

Tags: neural-network, keras, activation-function

I was testing how different hyperparameters would change the output of my multilayer perceptron for a regression problem

```
checkpoint = keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint("best_model.h5", save_best_only=True) 
# Initialising the ANN
model = Sequential()

# Adding the input layer and the first hidden layer
model.add(Dense(32, activation = 'relu', input_dim = X_train.shape[1]))

# Adding the second hidden layer
model.add(Dense(units = 8, activation = 'relu'))

# Adding the output layer
model.add(Dense(units = 1))

optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='mean_squared_error')
# Fitting the ANN to the Training set
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size = 100, epochs = 20, verbose=1, validation_split = 0.1, callbacks=[checkpoint])
```

and this model produced around 68% accuracy.

But when the activation functions for the hidden layers were changed to 'tanh', the accuracy jumped off a cliff to 0.07%!

I'm guessing it is something to do with tanh not being suited to regression?

Comment: Is it a classification or regression problem?  I see you're using an MSE loss, which suggests regression... (?)

Comment: its a regression problem

Comment: Since tanh forces all output values into the range [-1,1] If your y's take values outside that range, it will be hard / impossible for your model to produce correct predictions.  That's something to check.  If indeed your y's are outside the range, you could try to normalize them first, then use tanh, then un-normalize them.

Comment: How are you getting an accuracy measure in this problem?

Answer (score 1):

As posed, this question is quite difficult to answer as we do not have the data.
In any case, the first thing I can say is that $\mathrm{tanh}$ is an asymptotic function, hence there are large areas of the parameter space where its derivative is ~$0$, meaning the model struggles to learn.

This turns out to produce models less robust.